# A value of type 'DatabaseHelper?' can't be returned from the constructor 'DatabaseHelper' because it has a return type of 'DatabaseHelper'

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite, non-nullable

```
  static DatabaseHelper? _databaseHelper;

  DatabaseHelper._craeteInstance();

    factory DatabaseHelper(){
    if(_databaseHelper == null){
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._craeteInstance();
    }
    return _databaseHelper;
  }
```

currently, I cant return _databaseHelper because this function can only return DatabaseHelper value instead of DatabaseHelper?
I tried to change _databasehelper form DatabaseHelper? to DatabaseHelper, but in that way, the first two lines is errored, because the _databaseHelper must be initialized. what should I do to make both sides right?

Answer (score 0):

No need to check for null, just create your singleton once and return it.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

  DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

  factory DatabaseHelper(){
    return _databaseHelper;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add 'late' keyword.

```
static late DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
```

DatabaseHelper._craeteInstance();

```
factory DatabaseHelper(){
if(_databaseHelper == null){
  _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._craeteInstance();
}
return _databaseHelper;
```

}

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand why it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts.